# How to solve text encoding bug in Safari?

Tags: html, safari

Anybody had problem with text encoding in Safari 5.1.7( on Windows 7) ? In all browsers except Safari looks good, but one part of text looks like:

[image]

but should be

```
<h3>text text text</h3>
```

All h1 , ... , h6 tags looks like that in Safari, when I'm wrap text in

tag it turns into normal.

I have set encoding in layout file:

```
     <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Where is my problem ?

Comment: More information is needed, preferably a full example in jsfiddle, or something like that. It also matters what the elements really contain – just Ascii characters? Then perhaps there is some odd font set for headings.

Comment: It contains just text in English. font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica

Comment: @Jukka, maybe I give you a link to my site and you will look at it ?

Comment: Make sure to set the *Text Encoding* view in Safari to *Default*